# What is the origin of “give it the beans!”?

Tags: etymology, phrases, popular-refrains

There’s a phrase, possibly specific to British English, to “Give it [some/the] beans!” when referring to a task that somebody should put more effort into. It’s similar to “Give it some welly!”.

What I don’t know is.. what are the beans? Why am I giving them? And to whom?

I had a look around online and other than quite a few people acknowledging that this is something they say, I didn’t find much authoritative evidence for *why* we say it.

Comment: If it isn’t from Monty Python, it should be.

Comment: I've never heard it, and a bit of Googling suggests that it's not a very well-known expression.

Comment: Might it be related to *full of beans*, meaning *full of energy*?

Comment: There's a host of similar phrases: *give it some oomph*, *gusto*, *gas*, and the previously-mentioned *welly*. I guess people have substituted a lot of different things. Confusingly there's also an idiom "give someone beans" meaning [to scold](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+beans) but we'll ignore that. Not finding much but people on forums suggesting it's common among mechanics and car journalists. You could guess that beans might be considered a substitute for gas/petrol (either providing energy or flatulence) but as yet no evidence.

Comment: It's a phrase I've known since childhood, N Eng 60s/70s [always interchangeable with welly]. I've found reference to "full of beans" referring to horse food & the resulting energetic horse - maybe it's related.

Comment: It's interesting that mechanics/cars were mentioned. I usually see the phrase in the context where it's interchangeable with 'floor it'. Eg, to go faster in a car, pedal faster on a bike, etc.